# how to get hierarchy of employee reporting using postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I am new to postgres.

My postgres table name is **Employee** consisting of following columns

```
1.empid(uuid)//unique id
2.name
3.designation('engineer', 'asst.engineer', 'hr')
4.reporting_available('yes','no')
5.reporting_to('emp ids')//mapping to another employee
```

if suppose in organisation employee structure is like in below image

[image]

I need query for getting the hierarchy of jenny till reporting available (no)

Expected output

Jenny -> Sam -> Uday -> Sanjay.

Since sanjay dont report to anyone we should stop hierarchy at sanjay.

The similar questions

[Postgres query to get all the children ids](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50617761/6633337)

[SQL query to get the list of supervisor hierarchy. employee --> supervisor --> supervisor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49962130/6633337)

[how can I get all ids starting from a given id recursively in a postgresql table that references itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44874366/6633337)

did not have answer related to my question

Comment: the above duplicate question not working for me

Comment: WITH RECURSIVE subordinates AS (
 SELECT
 empid,
 reporting_to,
 name
 FROM
 employee
 WHERE
 empid = 'Emp107'
 UNION
 SELECT
 e.empid,
 e.reporting_to,
 e.name
 FROM
 employee e
 INNER JOIN subordinates s ON s.reporting_to = e.empid
) SELECT
 *
FROM
 subordinates;